# Identifying an application using network

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, sudo, software-sources

When I ran the following command `sudo netstat -lantp | grep -i stab | awk -F/ '{print $2 $3}' | sort | uniq` on the terminal to check which applications are using the network connection,  I got the following output

> firefox
>   prx

I cannot recognize  what `prx` is. Can someone please tell me what type of application is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Prey security and endpoint management system (https://preyproject.com/) names its application "prx" (at least it does on my Ubuntu 19.10)

Answer (score 0):

Find the PID of prx and its location on system using proc-fs. Then u can analyse what it is

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)